# Interpret the (visual) length of the branch in decision tree?

Tags: data-visualization, cart

I'm using the `tree` package in R to produce the following tree. The (visual) length of the first split is huge, and I wonder if this signifies something? Perhaps how much of the variance in the model is accounted by this split?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help on the `plot.tree` function (which is what you're calling if you call `plot` on a tree object) -- see `?plot.tree` -- explains what the branch length is used for if you don't specify `type=uniform`:

`type`  character string. If this partially matches "uniform", the branches are of uni-
$\quad\quad\quad$  form length. Otherwise they are proportional to the decrease in impurity.

The help can also be seen [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf) if you need it.